# how to import dir from outside the application in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, import, dir

I have a Yii webapp named A, and a second webapp named B that is inside A, I want to import `A/protected/vendors/` in some B controllers, so I want to write in the controller something like:

```
Yii::import('/../application.vendors.*');
```

how I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a path alias (to webapp A) on the top of your config file of webapp B (protected/config/main.php) for example:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('absolutePathToWebAppA', '/home/user/domains/site.com/public_html');
```

And in your controller in webapp B:

```
Yii::import('absolutePathToWebAppA.protected.vendors.*');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to require file once from this import ?

Comment: After the Yii::import function you, dont have require the files again. You can now call the object name by example: `$object = new Object` @MD.MD